# Skipping whitespace on new line?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I can't seem to get this correct. Basically if the line is blank inside the text file it should skip the line instead of numbering it. 
Ex: If the file contains, Apples,Oranges,Pineapples

> it should produce
>
> 1. Apples
> 2. Oranges
> 3. Pineapples
>
> or
>   1. Apples
>
> (blank)
>
> 2. Oranges
> 3. Pineapples

```
try {
     Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter file name with extension: ");
     File file = new File(reader.nextLine());

     reader = new Scanner(file);
     int counter = 1;
     while (reader.hasNextLine())
    {
      if (reader.equals(" ")){
      System.out.println();
    }else{
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("%2d.", counter++); // Use printf to format
    System.out.println(line);
    }
    }
     reader.close();
    } catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: You're checking for the reader to be equal to " ".  I think you want to be reading the line, using trim(), and then checking that line.equals("").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space  or " " is actually totally different to an empty line...
so the reason why is not working is the condition
`if (reader.equals(" ")){`.....

use instead the `String.isEmpty()` method, since this is what you need...

or try this:

```
            ...
        reader = new Scanner(file);
        int counter = 1;
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            final String line = reader.nextLine();
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("This is an empty line");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%2d.", counter++); // Use printf to format
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
...
```